# Group hints and warnings

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

Is there an option to group, or sort the hints and warnings messages by some criteria (e.g get all "Variable might not have been initialized" in a group under the messages window)?

Comment: Use the command-line compiler, grab the output and sort it any way you need.

Comment: The simple answer to your question is "no".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the IDE, there isn't. You can't do it using the command-line compiler either.

Answer (score -2):

One possible solution is to disable all warnings except one in the compiler settings/options under hints and warnings tab and so forth but this takes waaaayyy too long to do !

However if you really need this functionality on a daily basis for a large project, there is the possibility of saving this to an "option set" and then re-applying that when needed.

Haven't tried this myself yet, but good chance this will work.

Will try now because I need this =D

Hmm I discovered a little trick, it's enough to just press F and it will set it to False ! ;)

This will speed up the process ! ;)

OK Just tried it, it's a 50% solution.

Unfortunately hints are an all or nothing kind of thing, cannot be specified seperately :(